# Strange error in super method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

I understand that `super` is supposed to be used to initiate the super classes while within a subclass.  I do not understand why it is a problem when I try to execute it in the following code:

```
class A:
    v = 3
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g

class B(A):  

    def __init__(self, w):
        self.g = 7
        super().__init__(80)
```

And, then in the shell, I try the following:

```
r = B(90)
```

However, it throws an error:

```
    super().__init__(80)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

So I try modifying that line to the following:

```
super(A).__init__(80)
```

But of course, this also throws an error:

```
 super(A).__init__(80)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

In fact, I cannot get this to work, no matter what argument I put in for `super`.  What is the appropriate argument?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `super` on old style classes.  In Python 2, [classes that don't inherit from `object` are old style](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (this distinction is gone in Python 3).

Secondly, you should pass both the class (`B`) and the instance (`self`) to call instance methods.

```
class A(object):  # note object here
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(80)

B()  # works
```

If you want to use old style classes and call the parent class, reference it directly.  You should avoid using old style classes though.

```
class B(A):  # where A doesn't inherit object
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self, 80)
```

Answer (score 1):

The zero-argument form of `super` (i.e., `super()`) is only available in Python 3.  In Python 2 you must use the explicit form, in this case `super(B, self)`.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Since it's Python 2, you also need to make your classes new-style by defining `class A(object)`.